# Django project POST and GET requests not working with Nginx & Gunicorn

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I'm new to Django. I have a Django project and in my project, I use multiple APIs such as blockchain API for handling bitcoin transactions and cryptocompare API to get the latest bitcoin price and in my project, I have WebSocket messenger. I have set up the NGINX and Gunicorn for my production.

but all of the POST and GET requests in my project don't work and my project cannot communicate with external API and even local service like blockchain wallet API service. but when I run my project only with gunicorn

like this :

```
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:80 myproject.wsgi
```

it works fine

I'm a little bit confused.

here is my Gunicorn service in ubuntu server 18

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/myproject
ExecStart=/home/env/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 5 --worker-class gevent  --bind unix:/home/myproject/myproject.sock myproject.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And here is my Nginx configuration :

```
upstream channels-backend {
 server localhost:9001;
}
upstream django {

    server myproject:80;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name Domain.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location /static/ {
        root /home/myproject;
        add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
        expires 1y;
        add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31536000";
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/myproject/starbitsite.sock;
    }
#websocket
    location /ws/myprojectname/index/ {

        proxy_pass http://channels-backend;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }
}
```

Comment: Change your gunicorn binding other than 80, possible to 8080 and upstream django to 8080. Is this on the server already or just local?

Comment: Gunicorn has been bound to the Nginx socket file and I haven't set any port for Guincorn in service file you can see my Gunicorn service file on the top. it is on the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem solved. I use env variable in my application and I forgot to pass the environment variable in Gunicorn service